# Three.js and parts of model

Tags: json, html, three.js, webgl

Does anyone know how to access parts of 3d model when using Three.js. My 3d model consists of different parts, which I need to move individually.

Does anyone know how?
Thanks.

Comment: please show us some code describing how your model is constructed and what you have tried already.

Comment: You need to use the Object3D.traverse function in order to reach the individual parts of your model and then do whatever you want with them.

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar problem. What i did was to animate the model in blender, export the animation, and use three.js to call a segment of the animation when i need.